# how to use gitlab's cli to grant permission

Tags: automation, gitlab, command-line-interface

I'd want to add a user to many repositories. With restricted access to gitlab after a period of time, I believe it will be simple to handle if we employ certain recursive methods using the cli.

Is there a better solution for my present problem?

in short i have some list of repository in gitlab and i want add 1 user in all of the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could use `gitlab-rails console` although I would recommend using [GitLab API `members` endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html#add-a-member-to-a-group-or-project) to add user recursively to multiple projects:

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
     --data "user_id=<user_id>&access_level=XX" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/:id/members"
```

Valid access levels for projects are:

- No access (0)
- Minimal access (5) (Introduced in GitLab 13.5.)
- Guest (10)
- Reporter (20)
- Developer (30)
- Maintainer (40)